# Add data into laravel object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so i have this kind of class from my user controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $table_data = User::with('CU','pus')->select('id','id_cu','id_pus','name','username','gambar','status','created_at')->filterPaginateOrder();

        return response()
            ->json([
                'model' => $table_data
            ]);
    }
```

it is using trait called `filterPaginateOrder` and the end result that i receive are:

```
{
  "model": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "id_cu": 0,
        "id_pus": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "username": "test17",
        "gambar": "",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-02-27 06:37:10",
        "c_u": null,
        "pus": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "id_cu": 0,
        "id_pus": 1,
        "name": "tony",
        "username": "t0n1zz",
        "gambar": null,
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-01-01 11:11:11",
        "c_u": null,
        "pus": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Puskopdit BKCU Kalimantan"
        }
      }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "https://bkcuvue.dev/api/v1/user",
    "per_page": "2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 2,
    "total": 2
  }
}
```

so what if i want to add some data into it? inside `data` array for each array i want to add `"role":"master"` how do i do that?

i tried `$table_data->push('role','master')` and `$table_data->put('role','master')` from reading about collection (those query in laravel return collection right?) but none of those code working...

Comment: Well, you could add it manually with a foreach, or add `DB::raw('"master" as role')` in your select query.

Comment: how to do it with foreach or with db:raw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about it.

Add it via a foreach

```
$table_data = User::with('CU','pus')->select('id','id_cu','id_pus','name','username','gambar','status','created_at')->filterPaginateOrder();

foreach($table_data->data as $data) {
      $data->role = 'master';
}
```

Or add it into the SELECT:

```
$table_data = User::with('CU','pus')->select('id','id_cu','id_pus','name','username','gambar','status','created_at', DB::raw('"master" as role'))->filterPaginateOrder();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can override collection data of paginator object.

```
$table_data = User::with('CU','pus')->select('id','id_cu','id_pus','name','username','gambar','status','created_at')->filterPaginateOrder();
$table_data->getCollection()->each(function($user) {
    $user->role = 'master';
});

return response()->json([
    'model' => $table_data
]);
```